# How to install WordPress on existing database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a website already built in PHP with MySQL as database.

Now, I want to move on to WordPress, but keep my existing database.

How can I install WordPress and make it work with my existing custom database that I developed during my previous custom website?

Comment: You should probably install a fresh wp install, and then import your old data into the new db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install WordPress using the existing database credentials. Setup will create all the tables required to run WordPress on your existing database and rest of your database tables will remain as it is.

Now you can use your existing tables as per your need in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

First install fresh WordPress with DB connections. Then port existing data from old tables to new tables like below queries:

> insert into **NEWTABLENAME** select * from **OLDTABLENAME**.

Comment: That's not related. OP does not require data migration.

Comment: if you have similar tables which are required for WordPress. Then simple change database pointing  in WordPress config file. That would be accessible then.

Comment: No. In this scenario, you should make use of DB prefix provided by Wordpress

Comment: Then WordPress will create new schema/table with that prefix  in table names. But data need to be migrated which they have earlier in PHP application.

Comment: As mentioned at the first comment, OP does not require data migration at all. He can just leave the database tables in their original location.

Comment: Then, need to install WordPress which will point to existing db server and for safer side use DB prefix so that new tables will create with that prefix only.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty simple.

During Wordpress database information setup

Just write your new site or database name in the table prefix_..(name of new site)

[image]

hit summit wordpress will start a new installation

Check image:

[image]